# Tax not added in to Grand total

Tags: magento-1.9

I have one issue that tax is being display on checkout page but not being added into Grand total, Its showing fine on cart page. 
I did try with all admin settings but the issue remains same.
I did also tried with default Magento theme and issue is same . 
Any idea whats could be the reason ?

Thanks